# PhantomJS running a script against a specific HTML file?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, phantomjs, automated-tests, headless-browser

PhantomJS has the worst documentation ever. How do I run a simple .js against a specific html file? If I run phantomjs, I can use the REPL interface run `require`. How do I run that in such a fashion that `window.` is set as if a specific html file was the target?

I want to do something like

```
var $ = require('jquery');
$("div").attr('class');
```

and get the lists of classes... against this..

```
<html>
  <head><title>Hello World</title></title>
  <body>
    <div class="foo bar baz"> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based off of the [numerous examples](http://phantomjs.org/examples/):

```
'use strict';

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('your-file.html', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load file');
        phantom.exit(1);
    }

    page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js', function () {
        page.onConsoleMessage = function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        };

        page.evaluate(function () {
            console.log($('div').attr('class'));
        });

        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

I’ve never used PhantomJS before, and that took 10 minutes. Look harder!

Comment: Except you're using .includeJs which isn't CommonJS which is what I'm trying to test... Happen to know how to get the `require('module')` in there?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Inject requireJS and then use require to require jQuery. `requre` is not available in the page context and jQuery doesn't make sense outside of the page context.

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to use jquery for that. Working example:

```
var classes = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"),
                         function(el){ return el.className; });
```